# In Neo4j Cypher, How to iterate using LOAD CSV, UNWIND/FOREACH and WITH clauses?

Tags: foreach, neo4j, cypher, load-csv, unwind

In Neo4j, using Cypher, I want to run the below query for numbers 1 through 14 (i.e., `quantity1` to `quantity14`):

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM '<path>' AS row 
WITH row WHERE row.quantity1 IS NOT NULL
MATCH (m:main {main_id: row.main}) 
MERGE (q:quantity {quantity : row.quantity1}) 
MERGE (m)-[:main_has_quantity]->(q);
```

What the command does: The command reads a CSV, creates the quantity node (if it is not null and if it doesn't already exist) and then creates a relationship between the quantity node and it's corresponding main node. I want to do this for columns `quantity1` through `quantity14` in the CSV.

I tried to use `UNWIND` and `FOREACH` but both commands throw errors:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM '<path>' AS row 
UNWIND range(1,14) as i
WITH row WHERE row.quantity+toString(i) IS NOT NULL 
MATCH (m:main {main_id: row.main}) 
MERGE (q:quantity {quantity : row.quantity+toString(i)}) 
MERGE (m)-[:main_has_quantity]->(q);
```

I got the error:

> Variable `i` not defined (line 5, column 37 (offset: 246)) "MERGE
> (q:quantity {quantity : row.quantity+toString(i)})"

I used `FOREACH` in place of `UNWIND` but that did not work because I cannot use `WITH` clause inside `FOREACH`.

How best to achieve the result I am looking for?

P.S. I am using the Neo4j community version.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use squarw brackets here to be able to select dynamic properties

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM '<path>' AS row 
UNWIND range(1,14) as i
WITH row WHERE row['quantity'+toString(i)] IS NOT NULL 
MATCH (m:main {main_id: row.main}) 
MERGE (q:quantity {quantity : row['quantity'+toString(i)]}) 
MERGE (m)-[:main_has_quantity]->(q);
```